# Is there a way to generate feign client for Microservice in Micronaut with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, microservices, httpclient, micronaut, feign

I am trying to generate feign client for my Microservice.
I have tried all the options but could not find any specific solution for this in tech stack I am working with.
Using following tech stack:

- Gradle
- kotlin
- Micronaut

Note: I do not want to use HTTPClient provided by Micronaut.
Any help is appreciated.